# Why do we care about idempotent in distributed systems

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, distributed-system

I have a question on RESTful API - Why do we care about idempotent in distributed systems. Could you please let me know

Answer (score 5):

A service is idempotent if you can make the same call multiple times and it produces the same end-result.

In distributed systems, when you call a certain service/API, the service may fail (or worse, it may time-out and not even send you a failure response). In such cases, if the service is idempotent, you can simply call it again (any number of times) without the fear that calling it multiple times will have adverse effect.

If the service is NOT idempotent, you cannot simple call it again. You have to first check the actions taken by the previous call and then act based on that.

Comment: Even first checking what happened previously may not be sufficient in all cases, because two concurrent processes may simultaneously query the existing state, determine the operation should be retried, and then retry, resulting in the operation being performed two times. You'd require some locking mechanism or other protocol to ensure such a race condition does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Idempotentcy is especially important (aka something to care about) in a distributed system. Typically distributed systems include a large number of parts/components, many of which will be outside of the control of one another from one component developer to the next.

```
Benefits include:
 * improved thread safety
 * minimize complexity
 * easier to document (thus consume)
 * easier to test
 * data and state integrity will generally be easier to manage
```

Leveraging pure/idempotent functionality is especially useful in cases where you don't know if the caller code might be spamming one of your interfaces which could traditionally have a potential to put a system into a bad state. In addition, it makes the consumer documentation easier to understand, and minimizes some of the inherent complexities that come with an environment which by nature is not guaranteed to be thread safe.

If you need additional, or more specific use cases or examples of why a distributed system should care about idempotency as part of it's architecture please let me/us know.

*cheers*